# Calculating cells and storing in array to find the smallest value; "min"-function gives problems

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, min

I'm trying to calculate the cheapest alternative for a product out from a table, based on a user input.
The code is supposed to 
a)take an input number, the product size, (from K19 in User Interface sheet) and match it to the correct row in the table in order to find the different alternatives for this size. 
b) multiply the specific cost with the size so as to get the total cost for each alternative (hence the variants Mx, Nx, etc which are the specific costs for each alternative).
c) store the total costs in an array, and find the smallest of these numbers which is given back to the user in C45 in the user interface.

The described code sample:

```
Sub Calculate()

Dim var As Variant
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim Mx As Variant
Dim Nx As Variant
Dim Ox As Variant
Dim Px As Variant
Dim Qx As Variant
Dim Rx As Variant
Dim low As Variant
Dim cat As Variant

var = Range(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("User Interface").Range("K19"), Sheets("C-type").Range("L1:L10000"), 0)).Value

rownumber = var.Row

Mx = var * Range("M" & rownumber).Value
Nx = var * Range("N" & rownumber).Value
Ox = var * Range("O" & rownumber).Value
Px = var * Range("P" & rownumber).Value
Qx = var * Range("Q" & rownumber).Value
Rx = var * Range("R" & rownumber).Value

cat = Array("Mx", "Nx", "Ox", "Px", "Qx", "Rx")

low = Min(cat).Value

Sheets("User Interface").Range("C45").Value = low

Sheets("User Interface").Range("c45").Activate
Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True

End Sub
```

The problem is that VBA gives an error ("sub or function not defined") at `low = Min(cat).Value` even if from my findings I think I'm using the correct syntax. I couldn't find any viable solutions up until now. Could anyone help me troubleshoot?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
low = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(cat)
```

This piece of code should help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use `WorksheetFunction.Min` ?

[MSDN page for Excel built-in MIN function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-min-method-excel)

Comment: Possibly? I'm trying to find the smallest number in the array. trying "low = WorksheetFunction.Min(cat).Value" gives error "invalid qualifier" on the.min part. any advise on the syntax (the microsoft help page on that function was less than clear)?c Edit: found it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. When using Excel function `Min` you have to write `WorksheetFunction.Min` or `Application.Min`;
2. Don't use the `.value` on the function `Min`;
3. Your `low` value will always be 0 'cause your array doesn't contain any values... Write instead `cat = Array(Mx, Nx, Ox, Px, Qx, Rx)`

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Can you elaborate more on your point no 3? Am I doing it the wrong way to capture the values as calculated (or am I using the wrong syntax to calculate)? Edit: thanks! your point no 3 is well taken.

Comment: You're creating an array of strings (text chains) by using "", not an array of the values you have define for the `Mx`, `Nx`, ... variables.

Answer (score 1):

the code has some mistakes.

```
Sub Calculate()

Dim var As Variant
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim Mx As Variant
Dim Nx As Variant
Dim Ox As Variant
Dim Px As Variant
Dim Qx As Variant
Dim Rx As Variant
Dim low As Variant
Dim cat As Variant

var = Range(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("User Interface").Range("K19"), Sheets("C-type").Range("L1:L10000"), 0)).Value
'<~~ range error
rownumber = var.Row

Mx = var * Range("M" & rownumber).Value
Nx = var * Range("N" & rownumber).Value
Ox = var * Range("O" & rownumber).Value
Px = var * Range("P" & rownumber).Value
Qx = var * Range("Q" & rownumber).Value
Rx = var * Range("R" & rownumber).Value

'cat = Array("Mx", "Nx", "Ox", "Px", "Qx", "Rx")
cat = Array(Mx, Nx, Ox, Px, Qx, Rx) '<~~ quote is not need
low = WorksheetFunction.Min(cat) '<~~ use WorksheetFunction

Sheets("User Interface").Range("C45").Value = low

Sheets("User Interface").Range("c45").Activate
Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy. Lee for your comment. Any suggestion on what to do on the line "var = Range(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("User Interface").Range("K19"), Sheets("C-type").Range("L1:L10000"), 0)).Value"? 

I changed it to 'var = Range(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27"), Sheets("C-type").Range("L5:L345"), 0))" to narrow in on the exact range to match against but it says var is empty and giving me error "Subscript out of range"... Any aid would be appreciated (and I'll give answer points ofc)

Comment: @A.Doe: range is describe like this.  range("a1") .  it is string.

Comment: Am I getting the error because I'm trying to extract a "value" from a string?

Comment: @A.Doe:  "a1"  is string.